# Connecting a ReactJS frontend to a backend using xmpp-server

Tags: reactjs, xmpp, ejabberd

Connect client with server in xmpp:

I created the client with `@xmpp/component` and want to connect it with the backend. When I start the backend, it connects with the server and I can get the stanza: `status: online`.

If I start the react-app, it's also connecting to the server and I get a similar stanza.

But I don't know how to connect the front-end with the backend via the `xmpp-server`.
............................

Component connecting code:

```
this.xmpp = component({
      service: this.service,
      domain: this.domain,
      password: options.password,
});

this.xmpp.on("online", () => {
      console.log("Hey we're online!");
});
```

In both, the front-end and backend, the domain and password is same.

this.domain = `abc.domain.org`
this.password = `password`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `@xmpp/client` to create the client?